# Pass uint16_t array into function that takes uint8_t*

Tags: c, arrays, uint8t

In C, I'd like to pass a uint16_t array into a function that takes uint8_t:

```
bool fctn(uint8_t *data, size_t length);
```

I have this array, which is inside a struct:

```
typedef struct sStruct sStruct;
struct sStruct{
    uint16_t d[10];
}
sStruct myStruct;
```

So I do:

```
void test(sStruct structData) {
    fctn( (uint8_t*)structData->d[0], 10*sizeof(uint16_t) );
}
```

The length isn't the issue here, it's passing the array. If this array weren't a pointer already
I'm getting "error: cast to pointer from integer of different size", how can I make it look like an array of uint8_t? As far as that function is concerned, a uint16_t array will just look like a double length array of size uint8_t, but I'm not sure how to tell the compiler this...when the input is already a pointer.

If array 'd' wasn't inside a struct, but say just a global, I'd just do

```
fctn( (uint8_t*)d, 10*sizeof(uint16_t) );
```

What's the right way to do the function pass for an array inside a passed struct?

Comment: d[0] is a `uint16_t`, not a `uint16_t*`. Pass in `(uint8_t*)d`

Comment: Thank you, that clears up that question. I've modified the question for a second concern.

Comment: The `->` operator only applies to pointers. You can use `structData.d` the same way you used `d` before, it makes no difference.

Comment: Thanks! That does work. Why? d was an array, (uint8_t*) returns its address. structData->d is a pointer to the array, (uint8_t*) should return **, no?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, the usage of `(uint8_t*)` is as a type cast, so the resulting expression **must** be of type `uint8_t*`. That's the point of casting. To get the address of a variable, you can use the operator `&`. Casting is something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `uint16_t d[10];`, you are defining an array `d`. When you say `d[0]`, you access the first element of that array, which is of type `uint16_t`.  The function is expecting a pointer, so you should cast a pointer to your array, not an element in it:

```
fctn( (uint8_t*)d, 10*sizeof(uint16_t) );
```

When you do this, `d` is decayed from type `uint16_t[10]` to `uint16_t*`, then cast to `uint8_t*` before being passed to `fctn`.

As an aside, you can also use `sizeof(d)` to simplify your length calculation:

```
fctn( (uint8_t*)d, sizeof(d) );
```

Note that this only works if `d` is declared as an array (on the stack).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I'd also tried to pass (uint8_t)&d[0], which I thought would just take the data starting at the array start address, and case it to uint8_t, and I'm not sure why that wouldn't work. I was ultimately going to have the more in depth question about struct passing, but you all were too quick to answer before I could get my edits in:)